# Search in Google Sheet within same sheet

Tags: google-sheets, search, return, find, match

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Csbs.png)

Hi, I need to make a formula where I want to search text in Column A match or not with Column B, if yes return in Column C "found", if no "not found". i already tried to use function "INDEX", "MATCH" but not works. Pls help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In C2 you can try

```
=INDEX(if(len(A2:A), if(isnumber(match(A2:A, B2:B, 0)), "Found", "Not Found"),))
```

and see if that works?

Comment: thanks sir, it works but not so perfect. what is the other word that can i replace the formula "ISNUMBER" ? because my data not necessarily number, it can be alphanumeric. thx

Comment: Match returns the relative position of an item in a range that matches a specified value. I does not matter if the data is numeric or text.

Comment: Most welcome! Since you are new here, check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).